# With xlsxwriter: worksheet data_validation with strings converts a comma into \n

Tags: string, validation, drop-down-menu, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to use xlsxwriter to create a drop down list of strings in some cells.
In this list of strings I have 'Float [0,1]' but when I open the Excel file that is created, this string is splitted into 'Float [0' and '1]'.

How do I manage to have a string containing a coma in a drop down list?

I tried using """Float [0,1]""" but it doesn't change anything.

Here is what I wrote:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 12, 13, 14], 'Type':[None, None, None, None], 'Len':[2,2,2,2]})
out_path = r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Tests.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path , engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook  = writer.book

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    for i in range(2,len(df1)+2):
        cell = ''.join(['B' , str(i)])
        worksheet.data_validation(cell, {'validate': 'list', 'source': ['Boolean', 'Calculated value', 'Choice string', 'Float', 'Float [0,1]', 'Float < 0', 'Float <= 0', 'Float > 0', 'Float >= 0', 'Integer', 'Integer >= 0', 'Integer > 0']})
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have 'Float [0,1]' but when I open the Excel file that is created, this string is splitted into 'Float [0' and '1]'.

This is the same behaviour that you would see in Excel if you entered the string `Float [0,1]` manually in a list style data validation.

Excel treats the comma as a list separator in this context so it splits the string in two.

The only workaround (that I know of) would be to place the list values in cells and reference them as a range formula in the data validation. You could place the validation values on another worksheet or in hidden column.